# Asking for digest credentials while deploying a sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am getting a popup asking for **Digest** credential while deploying a sharepoint hosted app, i created a brand new sharepoint hosted app with out wrighting any code i deployed that in developer site, i got a page for trusting an app and i gave full control to the app at site collection level but once i trust the app i am getting an anothor popup asking for Digest creditials not sure what is that, could some one please help me what is the issue.

i am seeing a blank page when i enter my user name and password with my domain name and i am deploying the app in same domain server but from a different development machine through visual studio.

[image: Check the popup image]

Comment: Are you developing against sharepoint online or your on prem setup of sharepoint?

Comment: This is in on prem

Comment: what are the authentication providers configured on the web app?

Comment: claims based authentication

Comment: With what underlaying protocols?

Comment: http is the one

Comment: Sorry I meant authentication protocol. Windows, forms, trust provider...

Comment: its windows authentication through active directory

Comment: Are you developing on the same machine as the SharePoint server? ( Visual studio and sharepoint on same machine)

Comment: Yes, both are in same machine, i tried with different machine too but got the same error

Comment: Have you tried disabling loopback check?

Comment: Yes i disable loop-back check but still the same

Comment: Are you using the same domain for the SharePoint site and the app site?

Comment: No they are different domains

Comment: are both domains in the trust zone of internet explorer? (so IE passes along NTLM automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late to reply but I will answer anyways:-

1. Disable loopback popup:- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_foxhole/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way/
2. Add site/app domain to the trusted sites list and also if you are using proxy then add it to the proxy exceptions list.

All these steps resolved the sharepoint app errors or authentication problems for me.